# Git list commits that contain a string with diff around the changed line containing that string

Tags: git, git-log

Let's say I have a function called `MySuperFunction`. How do I list all commits that added/removed/changed/used this function, with the context of that change only?

For example, if commit `c` added a line using this function and 100 other lines, I want to see: The commit hash, the commit message, the commit's author and date (optional), and most importantly: a diff around the line where the function was added - with 5 lines before and after for context (with file name and line numbers), but not the entire 100 lines of the commit.

What I tried and why didn't it work:

- `git log -p | grep -C5 "MySuperFunction"` - does print the diffs with context, but no commit information.
- `git grep "MySuperFunction"` - only prints the current uses of `MySuperFunction`
- `git log -GMySuperFunction` - only prints the commit information, but no diff
- `git log -GMySuperFunction -p` - prints commit info and diff, but it prints the entire diff of each commit, not just the lines around `MySuperFunction`
- `git rev-list --all | GIT_PAGER=cat xargs git grep 'MySuperFunction'` - prints *all* commints that contain "MySuperFunction" in their *content*, not their *diff*

Is there any git log option for this, or do I have to write my own script that will take the output of `git log -GMySuperFunction -p` and filter through the diff only, leaving the commit information?

Comment: Use `git log -G <expr> --format=%H` to get the revision list, then use `git grep` on those revisions. (Ideally there would be a way to do the first half with `git rev-list`.)

Comment: "then use `git grep` on those revisions" any chance that you are going to elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: `git grep` takes an optional `<tree>` argument, which can be any commit specifier, hence `git grep foo master~5` prints usage of `foo` in commit `master~5`. You can pass multiple `<tree>` arguments, although if you have a huge number of those, you might want to split them up with `xargs` or something. (Presumably you'll also want a prefix `git log --no-walk` anyway so maybe collect revs, pipe to shell loop that does one git log and one git grep?)